# Unable to access DOM elements of template in backbone View

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a view like this:

```
var InvoiceForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(addform),
    initialize: function () {
        this.$("#buyer").val("test");
    }
});
```

I have the template addform containing the buyer id element. This isn't setting the value. I know i am doing something stupid here :)

Comment: is this on a user selected input box aka your trying to get the current input?

Comment: i am trying to set its value

Answer (score 2):

Backbone templates in Views aren't automatically rendered. In fact in the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/), there are some examples how you could do that.

If you use templates in your view, which should be rendered on initialize you can write your code like this :

```
var InvoiceForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(addform),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.render(); // Rendering your template in your this.el element
        this.$("#buyer").val("test"); // Setting the value of #buyer in your template
    }
});
```

You can later use this view like this:

```
var form = new InvoiceForm({ el: $("#wrapper_for_invoiceform") });
```

Check the demo in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hsn7J/

Comment: Many Thanks. Any other way to accomplish exactly what i want to?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish ? :D Backbone is probably the most elastic JS framework. I can't understand from your snippet the general purpose of your task.

Comment: yes sorry. See i have a text field in the template. I need to use typeahead plugin of bootstrap on it. So need to attach the same on the text field in the initialize func.

Comment: Well this seems like you should create another question. But you can replace `this.$("#buyer").val("test")` with `this.$("#buyer").typeahead(options)`, where options is the configuration of your `typeahead` ... check the manual https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead

Comment: then you just remove it from `initialize` and place it whenever you want in your code `form.render();` ( after you have called `var form = new InvoiceForm(...)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24226/discussion-between-drinchev-and-mrinal-purohit)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this on a click event - to change to the 'test' value, you could do it with the following

```
initialize: function(){
            this.model.on('change', this.render, this);         
        },

    render: function() {
            this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
            this.input = this.$('#buyer');
            return this;
        },

    events: {
     'click #buyer' : 'editValue',
    },

    editValue: function(){
        this.input.val("test");
    }
```

Comment: no not on click event. need to attach bootstrap typeahead on this element and hence need to access it